# Contributing to Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel

I am switching from Windows to Linux development, and loving it a lot. What is the best way to contribute to the kernel. I am very fluent in C and C++, and particularly am interested in contributing to threading. Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: "The best" is _very_ vague -- what is best for you might not be best for someone else. And vice versa. Running the `-rc` kernels and reporting bugs would probably be the most helpful for the community -- not enough people find bugs in the release candidate kernels. But each to their own, ya know?

Comment: Is this how we receive a guy new to StackOverflow with honest intentions of contributing to open source? By closing his question?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: thanks for the support! I think writing missing device drivers should be interesting

Comment: If you're really set to contributing, no matter the initial learning overhead, here's an idea: you could start a blog and tell about the experience of contributing to linux, places to start and such, to help others. In short, you could answer your own question yourself when you know the answer, and share it!

Comment: @Iceman Best of luck in driver land.  It can be a nasty place dealing with hardware.  Try looking through some of the [articles](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/content/how-participate-linux-community) people have posted in the past about how best to dive in.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: Good idea. I actually have been on the lookout for domain name.